# How to display array elements, if the number of elements is a variable

Tags: c#

I'm making a calculator in GUI, and I need some help.
When I enter some data in a text box, I need to store it in an array. This is how I thought of it.

```
    int numOfPackages;//used to get user input

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] weight = new int[numOfPackages];

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfPackages; i++)
        {
            weight[i] = Convert.ToInt32(weightBox.Text);
        }

        foreach (int i in weight)
            totalCostLabel.Text = "" + weight[i];

    }
```

And when I try to display the elements, it gives me the indexOutOfRange exception.
So, how do I display the elements of that array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please at least read the [doc about foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
foreach (int i in weight)
    totalCostLabel.Text = "" + weight[i];
```

should be

```
foreach (int w in weight)
    totalCostLabel.Text = "" + w;
```

Your current code iterates the array of weights, and tries to use the weight as an index into the array of weights, causing an index out of range exception.

Another problem is with the first loop: you are setting all values of `weight` to the same number:

```
weight[i] = Convert.ToInt32(weightBox.Text); // That's the same for all i-s
```

If weights are to be different, they should come from different weight boxes, or the string from a single `weightBox` should be processed in such a way as to produce multiple numbers (for example, by using `string.Split`).

Comment: Oh, I didn't explain that the numOfPackages is a number that user has to enter. But I incremented i, why is it trying to store the input in the same index?

Comment: @RomanGusan You should explain it then by editing the question. I would expect the `numOfPackages` to come from another text box, or perhaps a different UI element, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here. First is this:

```
    foreach (int i in weight)
        totalCostLabel.Text = "" + weight[i];
```

This is iterating the weight array and using each value in that array. You then use that value as an index. Take the following example:

```
weight[0] = 0
weight[1] = 1
weight[2] = 15
```

In your code, the first two entries will work because there is an index of 0 and an index of 1. But when it gets to the last entry, it looks for an index of 15. You can fix this two ways, the first is to use a regular for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < weight.Length; i++) 
{
    totalCostLabel.Text += weight[i];
}
```

This brings the second mistake. You aren't appending anything to your totalCostLabel in your code, you are just replacing the value. This will append all the values of weight together as one.

Another way to do this is to use the foreach loop:

```
foreach(int i in weight) 
{
    totalCostLabel.Text += i;
}
```

This is the same as above but you don't have to worry about indexing.

Bottom line, even after you fix your loop, you will probably need to fix the way that the label takes the text otherwise you won't get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted something more like?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnAdd.Enabled = false;
    }

    int[] weight;
    int entriesMade;
    int numOfPackages;

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(numEntriesBox.Text, out numOfPackages))
        {
            weight = new int[numOfPackages];
            entriesMade = 0;
            btnReset.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd.Enabled = true;
            totalCostLabel.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number of Entries");
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(weightBox.Text, out value))
        {
            weight[entriesMade] = value;
            weightBox.Clear();

            totalCostLabel.Text = "";
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= entriesMade; i++)
            {
                total = total + weight[i];
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    totalCostLabel.Text = weight[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    totalCostLabel.Text += " + " + weight[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            totalCostLabel.Text += " = " + total.ToString();

            entriesMade++;
            if (entriesMade == numOfPackages)
            {
                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
                btnReset.Enabled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Weight");
        }
    }

}
```